# Function to Search by date

Tags: php, symfony, date, repository

This is function for search by datetime .. i want to search just by date ( yy-mm-dd ) what i need to search just with date withount datetime .

I have tried all the options, but no one makes what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: remove this ."%" after $eDate and try again

Answer (score 0):

if it is Mysql then you can use [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function
as something like this

```
$qb->AndWhere("DATE(m.startDate) = :start");
$qb->setParameter('start',date('Y-m-d'));
```

for Postgres like this

```
$qb->AndWhere("m.startDate::date = :start");
$qb->setParameter('start',date('Y-m-d'));
```

Doctrine have to be setup before https://simukti.net/blog/2012/04/05/how-to-select-year-month-day-in-doctrine2/

```
$emConfig = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
    $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DATE', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date');
```

Comment: I changed my answer. I think the problem in Doctrine query builder